# How can I regenerate health faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm in bit of a conundrum. My question is, how do you regenerate health faster on Minecraft servers? I know that plugins exist for this purpose, but is there a way solely with WorldGuard, Multiverse, and Essentials and without pertinent potion effects? I have tried messing around with flags heal-min-health (20), heal-amount (alternating between numbers between 5-20), heal-max-health (20), and restarting the server. However, nothing satisfying has come as a result. To reiterate, is there a way to regenerate health faster using WorldGuard, Multiverse, and Essentials?

Comment: Do you want to do this in a specific area, or in the whole world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting the `heal-delay` flag to a lower value:

```
/rg flag {name} heal-delay {amount}
```